# Preview image of map

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit

How can I make a preview icon like in the iPhone Map application?

[Screenshot http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/1619/img0016x.png](http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/1619/img0016x.png)

Is there a function for this?

Comment: What do you mean? Rounded corners? Border? Map and pin?

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I just found out, that Apple provides code in their GeocoderDemo sample from Apple at GeocoderDemo/PlacemarkViewController.m in the function cellForMapView (MKMapView)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 7 use MKMap​Snapshotter. From [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/):

```
MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
options.region = self.mapView.region;
options.size = self.mapView.frame.size;
options.scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"path/to/snapshot.png"];

MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];
[snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"[Error] %@", error);
        return;
    }

    UIImage *image = snapshot.image;
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
}];
```

---

Before iOS7 do one of the following:

- Add a live map and disable interaction.
- Use the Google Static Maps API (explained below).
- Create a MKMapView and render it to an image. I tried this (see previous edit) but couldn't get the tiles to load. I tried calling needsLayout and other methods but didn't work.

Apple's deal with Google is more reliable than a free API, but on the bright side, it is really simple. Documentation is at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

This is the minimum amount of parameters for practical use:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.416878,-3.703530&zoom=15&size=290x179&sensor=false

A summary of the parameters:

- `center`: this can be an address, or a latitude,longitude pair with up to 6 decimals (more than 6 are ignored).
- `format`: png8 (default), png24, git, jpg, jpg-baseline.
- `language`: Use any language. Default will be used if requested wasn't available.
- `maptype`: One of the following: roadmap, satellite, hybrid, terrain.
- `scale`: 1,2,4. Use 2 to return twice the amount of pixels on retina displays. 4 is restricted to premium customers.
    Non paid resolution limits are 640x640 for 1 and 2.
- `sensor`: true or false. Mandatory. It indicates if the user is being located using a device.
- `size`: size in pixels.
- `zoom`: 0 (whole planet) to 21.

There is a few more to add polygons, custom markers, and style the map.

```
  NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"http://maps.googleap..."];
  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: thanks! I put it in an additional view (addSubview) and added #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: Sadly when I tried my answer the map came back with blank tiles. I guess some debugging would find the trick but right now I'm following Matt advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google Maps Static API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to generate an image instead of loading an entire `UIMapView`.